# How to "cascade" Windows 7 file details throughout a folder tree?

Tags: windows-7, windows

In Windows 7, is it possible to set the file details you want to view on a top-level folder and then have that view cascade to all files in all subfolders, whether those subfolders already exist or are created later?

Here's my immediate situation: I want to see the Total Editing Time on all Word files contained within a folder and its subfolders.

As best I can tell, I must set the details *within* one folder and/or subfolder at a time (i.e., open the folder or subfolder that contains the files, and then set the details). [[ See the GIF I uploaded for a screenshot. ]]

I did see another discussion that suggested the only way to get a cascade is to mess with the registry key. But I remain hopeful there is a simpler way to do what I (and I'm sure a gazillion of my very best friends) want to do.

Also, is the solution or solutions for Win7 true for newer Windows?

[image: Example of Win7 file details]

Answer (score 0):

You have to first set it up in the View menu, and then replicate it via the Tools menu.

1. Open an Explorer window.
2. Customize the details for one of your high-level folders

> Example: D drive > View > Choose details ...

3. Apply the settings from step 2 to all of your folder

> Example: Tools > Folder options... > View tab > Apply to folders

Now that I've done it a few times, I realize that in Step 2, I just need to check the boxes to cover all of the bases.

I.e., I start at the D drive where the only thing I see (in my environment) are the folders in the D drive. Any one folder could contain a mix of docx, xls, png, txt, jpg, mp4, etc. files.

At the D drive level, I set the details that I want to see for all file types and for specific file types.

When I drill into the folders, I'll see only the details that the system is able to report for specific file types.

Hope this answer is useful to others.

And, for sure, if you have your own tips or do's and don'ts to add to this thread, then please do!